# Is it possible to show two Databricks dashboards side by side in another Databricks dashboard (or otherwise)

Tags: databricks

I have two Databricks dashboard I would like to display side by side.  Is this possible?

Comment: are you talking about Databricks SQL dashboards or dashboards in notebooks?

Answer (score 0):

As a work around, I was able to download each dashboard as an html file and then use something like the code shown below to display them side-by-side.

```
<style> 
html,
body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
#doc1,
#doc2 {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 49%;
  height: 100%
}
iframe {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  border: none;
}
#doc1 {
  background-color: red;
}
#doc2 {
  background-color: blue;
}
</style>

<html>

<head>
</head>

<body translate="no">

  <div id="doc1">
    <iframe src="file:///C:/Users/gresh/Downloads/000-basic-characterization-hiv.html"></iframe>
  </div>

  <div id="doc2">
    <iframe src="file:///C:/Users/gresh/Downloads/000-basic-characterization-hiv-enc.html"></iframe>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```